# MongoDb connection using node js failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using termux in my android to connect to a mongodb atlas database
and i used the following code

```
const express=require('express');
const {MongoClient}=require("mongodb");
const app=express()
let db;
async function start()
{
const uri="mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.4zlmiaq.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client=new MongoClient(uri);
await client.connect();
db=client.db();
app.listen(3000);
} 
start();
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
allAnimals=db.collection("Animals").find().toArray();
res.send(allAnimals);
});
```

what i already did:
●changed the user access to admin level
●white list the ip by adding my device ip.
The result was

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:207
                    callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));
                             ^

MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:207:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:60:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at processIncomingData (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20)
    at MessageStream._write (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:391:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:332:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:336:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  connectionGeneration: 0,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
}
```

Comment: Did you replace the username and password in URL with your database username and password.

Comment: Yes.i replaced it for posting here

Comment: Okay then 1st try IP 0.0.0.0 in whitelist IPs to check if it works on all router

Comment: No change.its the same.

Comment: Can you make sure that the password you are using is not the account password? It should be you user password and user username

Comment: yes .i made sure of that i tried with different user accounts and nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.i solved it.
I removed the user and added an admin with full capabilities.